# find ip in txt content php

Tags: php, ip

I have a text file : ban.txt have content

```
a:5:{i:14528;s:15:" 118.71.102.176";i:6048;s:15:" 113.22.109.137";i:16731;s:3:"  118.71.102.76";i:2269;s:12:" 1.52.251.63";i:9050;s:14:"123.21.100.174";}
```

I write a script to find and ban IP in this txt

```
<?php
$banlist = file("ban.txt");

foreach($banlist as $ips ) {

    if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == $ips) {
        die("Your IP is banned!");
    }
}
?>
```

Can help me to list IP in this content, i m a newbie php. Thanks very much

Comment: If the file is encoded in JSON, then you need to run json_decode. They you can loop through the resulting array

Comment: The existing ban.txt looks like the output of a madman. It's easily fixed, but is there some reason why some IPs have extra spacing or some elements have 3 components and others 2? (e.g. s:Number:String vs i:Number vs a:Number:Object) ?

Comment: Just curious why there are spaces right before ips?

Comment: I dont know JSON encoded ?? . Can u help more, thanks

Comment: It looks like the file is supposed to be a [`serialized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array, but it appears invalid, and the values it contains also seem somewhat nonsensical...

Comment: The IP always in "ip". Can help me ?

Comment: I can't change output , but the ip always is "ip" or " ip". Always in " "

Comment: The problem is that your IP "list" is garbled and broken. You need to fix it first or fix whatever is producing it.

Comment: That is absurd serialized garbage.

Comment: @MIF is that from a php forum (phpbb, ipb, etc) ? if so could you provide the name of the forum it might help to solve your problem in a easier way.

Comment: I just try and have a list without space  a:5:{i:13716;s:12:"1.52.251.63";i:16731;s:14:"70.241.74.116";i:2269;s:12:"1.52.251.63";i:6048;s:15:"113.22.109.137";i:9050;s:14:"123.21.100.174";}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look **this is an acknowledged crap solution based on an unclear question**

Regex never seems a great solution, but I don't have a lot of detail on how consistent the file is.

**1. Isolate "s" segments in your ban.txt**

As such, and my regex isn't fantastic, but this regex should match the "s" segments which appear to be for IP bans (although your comment stating "The IP always in "ip"" confuses this a little).

```
Regex: s:[0-9]+:"[ ]*[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+";
```

**2. Isolate the IPs within each "s" segment**

Once we have these segments, we can strip the start bit up to the actual IP (i.e. turn `s:123:"192.168.0.0";` into `192.168.0.0";`), and afterwards trim the end quotation mark and semi-colon (i.e. `192.168.0.0";` to `192.168.0.0`):

```
Regex for start junk (still need to trim end): s:[0-9]+:"[ ]*
Regex for end junk: [";]+
```

**3. Example Code**

This would give us this PHP code:

```
$banText = file_get_contents("ban.txt"); 

/* Evil, evil regexes */
$sSegmentsRegex = '/s:[0-9]+:"[ ]*[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+"/';
$removeStartJunkRegex = '/s:[0-9]+:"[ ]*/';
$removeEndJunkRegex = '/[";]+/'; /* Could use rtrim on each if wanted */

$matches = array();

/* Find all 's' bits */
preg_match_all($sSegmentsRegex, $banText, $matches); 
$matches = $matches[0]; /* preg_match_all changes $matches to array of arrays */

/* Remove start junk of each 's' bit */
$matches = preg_replace($removeStartJunkRegex, "", $matches); 
$matches = preg_replace($removeEndJunkRegex, "", $matches); 

foreach($matches as $ip) {
    if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == $ip) {
        die("Your IP is banned!");
    }
 }

print_r($matches); /* Shows the list of IP bans, remove this in your app */
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/S9rTQe

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\aa.php on line 9

Comment: a:5:{i:13716;s:12:"127.0.0.1";i:16731;s:14:"70.241.74.116";i:2269;s:12:"1.52.251.63";i:6048;s:15:"113.22.109.137";i:9050;s:14:"123.21.100.174";} . This is a output , i try to remove space. Can u check for me ?

Comment: Fixed, try new code (was a couple of mistakes as don't have handy PHP interpreter right now).

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\aa.php on line 11

Comment: A have a new error : Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\aa.php on line 14 . Hi , may be i wrong ?

Comment: Yeah I've just found a PHP interpreter online. I'll fix you up and link the snippet, just give me a moment :P

Comment: Okey ,Thanks you very much , i can wait , dont worry.

Comment: Fixed - apparently needed to make it `$matches[0]` for the `preg_replace` (`preg_match_all` must make it an array of arrays).

Comment: OK, it work very good. Thanks u and thanks so much. Very thanks ,

Comment: Np - I put a little change so it's easier to print_r the ips that it's detecting as banned, just for your testing. Obviously remove the print_r in production.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, please hit the 'Tick' to accept the answer.